# How to add Data dynamically in ListView in Android

Tags: android

I  have  *ListView* which as one *TextView* in each Row. and im discovering some upnp devices in the network, once discovered i have to add the name of the discovered device into the List. **My question is how to update the List Dynamically.so anyone Please help me**.

thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the List/ArrayList you're using as your list adapter's data source, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your ListView.

Comment: hi kcoppock thanks for the help, so u mean initially i have to provide an empty ArrayList, and then add discovered data into arrayList right.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. I don't think there are any issues with providing an empty ArrayList to a ListView, so you shouldn't have a problem doing that.